# Find missing entries in link table

Tags: t-sql

I use SQL-Server 2008 and have the following tables.

users

```
userid
1
2
3
```

objects

```
objectid | category
9        | A
8        | B
7        | A
6        | C
```

userobjects

```
userid | objectid
1      | 9
3      | 7
3      | 6
```

As you can see, userobjects is a link table. Unfortunately it is missing some entries. I could include them with a script but I wonder if there is a solution in sql.

For every userid and every objectid that belongs to category 'A' there should be an entry in userobjects. So what I wanted to have is this:

```
userid | objectid
1      | 9
1      | 7
2      | 9
2      | 7
3      | 9
3      | 7
3      | 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could include them with a script but I wonder if there is a solution
>   in sql.

This is a select query using `UNION` (here is [SQL-DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/37a28/7));

```
select u.userId, o.objectId
from objects o cross join users u
where o.category = 'A'
union
select u.userId, o.objectId
from users u join userobjects uj on u.userid = uj.userId
     join objects o on uj.objectid = o.objectid
where o.category <> 'A'
order by u.userid,o.objectid desc

--RESULTS
userId  objectId
1       9
1       7
2       9
2       7
3       9
3       7
3       6
```

Comment: +1 but you might want to consider using UNION ALL since the first set is guaranteed to exclusive of the second set

Comment: @ConradFrix: thanks for your comment & +1. I don't understand what you mean. In general, `UNION` is used for distinct records and `UNION ALL` brings all the records. But applying to this query does not make a difference as two queries are exclusive from one another (as `='A'` and `<>'A'` filters used).

Comment: If you had written this on a different question `SELECT DISTINCT APrimaryKeyField FROM ATable` I would have written the comment *you might want to consider dropping DISTINCT since APrimaryKeyField is guaranteed to be unique* So using UNION ALL is better for the same reason dropping an unnecessary DISTINCT is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without a UNION using a LEFT join and a non-traditional INNER JOIN to objects

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.userid, 
                o.objectid 
FROM   users u 
       LEFT JOIN userobjects uj 
              ON u.userid = uj.userid 
       INNER JOIN objects o 
               ON uj.objectid = o.objectid 
                   OR ( o.category = 'A' ) 
ORDER  BY u.userid, 
          o.objectid DESC
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/37a28/21)